# Get last entry in OData EntitySet (IoTMMS)

Tags: javascript, api, odata, sapui5

I'm trying to get the last entry from an OData EntitySet from the IoTMMS (a SAP Cloud Platform Service).

Thank you!

- OData API: https://iotmmsUSERtrial.hanatrial.ondemand.com/com.sap.iotservices.mms/v1/api/http/app.svc/SYSTEM.T_IOT_4212F80B4D7D95539D0C
- [Destination (img)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5qmm.png): complete URL: https://iotmmsUSERtrial.hanatrial.ondemand.com/com.sap.iotservices.mms/v1/api/http/app.svc
- neo-app.js

```js
{
  "welcomeFile": "/webapp/index.html",
  "routes": [
    {
      "path": "/resources",
      "target": {
        "type": "service",
        "name": "sapui5",
        "entryPath": "/resources"
      },
      "description": "SAPUI5 Resources"
    },
    {
      "path": "/test-resources",
      "target": {
        "type": "service",
        "name": "sapui5",
        "entryPath": "/test-resources"
      },
      "description": "SAPUI5 Test Resources"
    },
    {
      "path": "/com.sap.iotservices.mms/v1/api/http/app.svc",
      "target": {
        "type": "destination",
        "name": "sensordata_tut"
      },
      "description": "sensordata_tut"
    }
  ],
  "sendWelcomeFileRedirect": true
}
```

- manifest.json

```js
{
 "_version": "1.7.0",
  ...
  "dataSources": {
   "sensordata": {
    "uri": "/com.sap.iotservices.mms/v1/api/http/app.svc",
    "type": "OData",
    "settings": {
     "odataVersion": "2.0",
     "localUri": "localService/metadata.xml"
    }
   }
  }
 },
  ...
 "sap.ui5": {
  ...
  },
  "contentDensities": {
   "compact": true,
   "cozy": true
  },
  "models": {
   "i18n": {
    "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
    "settings": {
     "bundleName": "sensordata_tut.i18n.i18n"
    }
   },
   "sensordata": {
    "dataSource": "sensordata",
    "type": "sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel",
    "preload": true
   }
  },
  "resources": {
   "css": [{
    "uri": "css/style.css"
   }]
  }
 }
}
```

- Master.view.xml (the binding works)

```html
<mvc:View xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" controllerName="sensordata_tut.controller.Master" displayBlock="true">
 <App>
  <pages>
   <Page title="{i18n>title}" content="{sensordata>/T_IOT_4212F80B4D7D95539D0C}">
   <content>
       <StandardTile title="Sensor 1" info="{sensordata>G_CREATED}" icon="sap-icon://temperature" number="{sensordata>C_TEMP}" numberUnit="Celsius" infoState="Success" id="__tile0"/>
   </content>
   </Page>
  </pages>
 </App>
</mvc:View>
```

- Master.controller.js

```js
sap.ui.define([
 "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"
], function(Controller) {
 "use strict";

 return Controller.extend("sensordata_tut.controller.Master", {
     
     onInit: function() {
           var url = "/com.sap.iotservices.mms/v1/api/http/app.svc";
           var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel(url);
           console.log(oModel);
         
     }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you creating a new model in your onInit? If you define a model in the manifest, it is set in the Component level. To retrieve it, and use it in the controller just do:

```
onInit(){
  var myOdataModel = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("sensordata");
  console.log(myOdataModel);
}
```

#### EDIT:

How to get last entry in an OData EntitySet: Update your aggregation binding

```
<Page title="{i18n>title}" content="{path:'sensordata>/T_IOT_4212F80B4D7D95539D0C', sorter:{path: 'G_CREATED', descending: true}, length: 1}">
```

Comment: Thank you! Well this works, I expected that I have to explicit get an OData Model to make use of the OData Query options. I tired to add                 'urlParameters: { "$top": "1",  "$orderby": "G_CREATED desc"}' so that I only get the last item from the odata request and also add 'defaultOperationMode: sap.ui.model.odata.OperationMode.Server'. So that that the sorting is done on the server. But this also didn't work. 
Do you have an idea how to get the last item in the model with out claiming the client?